# USERELATIONSHIP gives incorrect result when using FILTER Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have inactive relationship AccountingDate

[image]

My date type slicer:

```
DateTypeSelected = SELECTEDVALUE('Date Type Slicer'[Date Type],"Effective Date")
```

[image]

When I use `FILTER` it  gives me incorrect value.

```
NB Premium by AccDate = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM(fact_Premium[Premium]), FILTER(fact_Premium, fact_Premium[PolicyType] = "New Business"),
        USERELATIONSHIP(fact_Premium[AccountingDate], dim_Date[Date])
        )
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was giving the wrong number because inside `FILTER` I need to use slicer table table

**so instead :**

```
FILTER(fact_Premium, fact_Premium[PolicyType] = "New Business")
```

**should be:**

```
FILTER(dim_PolicyType, dim_PolicyType[PolicyType] = "New Business")
```

--============================================================================

```
NB Premium by AccDate = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM(fact_Premium[Premium]), FILTER(dim_PolicyType, dim_PolicyType[PolicyType] = "New Business"),
        USERELATIONSHIP(fact_Premium[AccountingDate], dim_Date[Date])
        )
```